# Как перемещаться по папкам через команды терминала в PyCharm?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Я знаю, что для перемещение в папку ниже можно воспользоваться командой **cd papkaname**. Но как из этой папки вернуться в папку выше? Есть ли для этого команда какая-либо?

Comment: `````cd ..`````?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать команду `cd ..`, но python и Pycharm тут ни при чём.

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Pycharm использует обычную `cmd` в окне терминала.
Вы можете использовать весь командлет обычной `Windows` консоли.

`cd <PATH>`, а конкретнее, как уже сказали, `cd ..`

Comment: Если уже сказали зачем дублировать?

Comment: Кто-то сказал про cmd в терминале?